# Is it possible to intercept/handle/parse the HTML inside of the body tags before the browser?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm wondering if it is at all possible to take whatever is inside of the  tags, run it through Javascript and manipulate it before throwing it back for the browser to then parse.

I'm sure it can be done, however it may not be as straightforward as I am suggesting.

For instance, is there a way for the Javascript to take the entire source code of the HTML file and put it into a var as text?

Comment: A bit too vague don't you think? Could you be more specific what you are actually trying to do?

Comment: Why exactly are you "sure it can be done"?

Comment: One example would be to remove certain things from the HTML before the browser has a chance to use resources to fetch them. For instance, any image without a certain class name would be removed from the DOM.

Comment: Because anything is possible, we put men on the Moon and right now there are robots on Mars.

Comment: You might want to recheck my answer. I gave you an example of how to remove stuff from DOM before its content is loaded by browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The earliest point at which you could actually start thinking about manipulating a page which hasn't finished loading is when the page DOM is loaded. Any attempt to do so before that point is most likely going to result in failure. That's the reason most JavaScript frameworks/libraries have special methods which allow users to invoke their code once DOM is loaded.

**EDIT:** If you just want to remove certain elements from the page before they are loaded your best bet is to remove them form the page DOM right after the DOM has been loaded which will prevent the browser from even getting the chance to load the unwanted resources. I will give you an example which makes use of jQuery but only because it has a nice method called **ready()** which is fired right after the DOM has been loaded. That said this is perfectly achievable with plain JavaScript, though a bit more complicated.

```
$('document').ready(function(){
    $('.unwanted-elements').remove(); // You can use any other selector you want.
});
```

This code will remove the unwanted elements from the DOM tree before the resources which are potentially inside of them are even loaded.

Comment: When you say page DOM is loaded, you mean when it's finished loading, correct?

Comment: Exactly, after the DOM has been completely loaded. That is the moment when browsers become fully aware of all the page elements so you can safely reference them.

Answer (score 4):

I don't know if it's possible with straight JS, but a tricky way of achieving the same effect would be to set your body to `display:none`, then have your JS parse and spit it back out, then set body back to `display:block`.

Comment: Expect heavy penalties from search providers like Google if you do so!

Comment: Doing this, the browser would still load any images, etc. Trying to avoid that.

Answer (score -1):

Dump all your BODY HTML into a JS variable from the server end and do the following

```
 <html>
      <head>
           <script type="text/javascript">
                var bodyHTMLStr = "<?=dumpPageBody?>";
                //Create a element dynamically and dump 'bodyHTMLStr' as innerHTML to it
                var dummyDIV = document.createElement("DIV");
                dummyDIV.innerHTML = bodyHTMLStr;

                //Now you can all the processing you want. Once done dump dummyDIV html into BODY's innerHTML
           </script>
      </head>
      <body>
      </body>
 </html>
```

Comment: Won't have access to any server side language.